# Closure in a array that is a class property

Tags: php, oop, lambda, closures

I'm having a corner case where I'd like to put a closure in a class property array

```
class Foo {

    public $bar = array(
        'baz' => function(){},
    );

}
```

However, PHP does not seem to be happy with closure definitions in a class property context. Is there a way to overcome problem ?

Comment: Do it in the constructor

Comment: @PeeHaa: In case you down-voted my answer: I really don't care that much, but I would like to know the reason...